# Create a color scale with css

Tags: css

I need a color scale that has the full spectrum starting with red and ends with blue. A simple gradient would not work as its directly blends from red to blue. So I wonder which colors and a which position I have to add.

Comment: Like this: http://dabblet.com/gist/6520530 ? Depends on how precise you want, you can add more steps to the linear gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came up with this solution: http://jsbin.com/uzelInU/1/ using the following color/position combination:

```
#ff0000 0%, 
#fcfc00 25%, 
#35d600 50%, 
#00fcfc 75%, 
#3f00ff 100%
```